# Installation using GitHub

Tags: github, installation

I don't know the first thing about programming, but I came across something I would like to install using GitHub.

**These are the steps:**

- Fork or Clone the repository.
- Run `npm install` while in the directory of the project.
- Open `chrome` and `load` in a new "`unpacked extension`" from the extensions screen.
- Open project folder and load in the src folder in `/chrome`.
- Open `/app/containers/auth.js/sagas.js/` and edit the variable `--CHROME_EXTENSION_ID` to the one found in your chrome extensions screen.
- Run `npm` start in the root directory of the project.
- Navigate to `localhost:3000/login` and the chrome extension will handle the login process.

I got the "`clone the repository`" part lol.
Is this something that anyone can easily teach me how to do or does it require some kind of programming knowledge?

I'm sorry for the layman post.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

> - Fork or Clone the repository. (this is covered above)

You should start by searching Google for "How do I clone using git".  Git is a tool, GitHub is just a cloud service for git.  git has help built in.

git help

Typically you would do this assuming you have git installed.

```
git clone <git repo>
```

Git questions need to go on SuperUser.com too.

---

So, it looks like you are trying to install something for NodeJS.  Installing NodeJS can sometimes be tricky, but use Google if you get stuck with specific errors.

> - run npm install while in the directory of the project.

Typically you just need to *cd* into the folder you just cloned.
Then you just run:

```
npm install
```

This installs the libraries (dependencies) that the program you are using needs. Keep an eye out for any warnings.

> - Open chrome and load in a new "unpacked extension" from the extensions screen.

Open Chrome and paste this URL: `chrome://extensions/`

> - Open project folder and load in the src folder in /chrome.

Ideally, you have a text editor like *Atom* or *Sublime Text*.  You'll want to open the Git folder you 'cloned' earlier.  Both are great, *Atom* is free.

> - Open /app/containers/auth.js/sagas.js/ and edit the variable --CHROME_EXTENSION_ID to the one found in your chrome extensions screen.

I would need to see the file to help here. If it's Java it might look like this:

```
var CHROME_EXTENSION_ID = "SOME_ID";
```

or it could be in JSON format:

```
{
    CHROME_EXTENSION_ID: "SOME_ID"
}
```

> - run npm start in the root directory of the project.

So, inside the folder you cloned you run this to start a NodeJS server.

```
npm start
```

This typically will start a local server on your computer.

> - Navigate to localhost:3000/login and the chrome extension will handle the login process.

An id all does well, you would just be able to open this URL in Chrome.

```
http://localhost:3000/login
```

If all went well you should be able to point the browser at your computer and see whatever you are expecting.

Comment: I installed git and did the cloning. I searched for a few hours on how to do the rest of the steps but I couldn't learn enough to do it alone. I will post on that website. Thanks!

Comment: I'll update my answer with the other things you mentioned.

Comment: I am getting lots of Warnings during the npm install named "add remote git" and "deprecated". What do they mean?

Comment: I was able to do every step but in the end all I got was a blank screen on chrome.    2 things: when I was editing the text I replaced everything that said "CHROME_EXTENSION_ID" with the ID on the extension screen. Was that the correct thing to do?  Also, during the npm install I got so many warnings, about missing webpacks and lots of other stuff. What should I do about that?

Comment: 'npm install' issues really depend on your OS.  You usually need to Google them to figure out what is going on.  You should really reach out the the community that wrote the product you are trying to install.  The GitHub Issues page for the project is a good place to start.